# How to quickly switch to two from one mazimized window into two half screen splits and back?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, window-manager

Sometimes when editing code I need to quickly find something in a browser like documentation for example and have it in my sight for some time and then when I'm done it's not needed anymore.

Right now I have to do `alt-tab` to switch to other browser then `ctrl-super-left` to make it half screen etc.

I do that often enough to find that annoying. How to automate this task?
The exact behaviour I want is this.

I press a key combination like alt-tab and I can pick a application that I want to show beside. Right after I've chosen it both window should be shown in a split. When I'll be done I'll press another key combination and first window should be maximised and (important detail) second window should be hidden with restoring it's original layout and size.

Comment: This is *just* to close to an assignment. This is not asking for a solution, but simply asking to  realize what *you* have in mind. Not really how it works here.

Comment: I just know what I want, is that a bad thing? I've learned that the thing that does what I want is probably called tiling window manager, so I'm investigating i3 now.